# React Native Error: react-native-sensor-manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native, sensormanager

I'm trying to use the react-native-sensor-manager in order to get the user steps and count that. But the problem is after I installed this package and did all the configuration as in the [documentation](https://github.com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-manager). I don't know what is wrong although a did all the steps correctly. I get this error when I run my project. So the build doesn't become compeleted and project is running.

Here is more about the error:

```
    Task :react-native-sensor-manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
E:\Project\React Native Projects\walk_tacker2\node_modules\react-native-sensor-manager\android\src\main\java\com\sensormanager\AccelerometerRecord.java:9: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-sensor-manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```